# Update enum in groovy using meta programming

Tags: groovy, enums

I have an enum.

```
enum Status {A,B,C}
```

Is it possible to add another status using meta programming?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. How do you intend to use this? There might be another solution.

Comment: enum is from external jar file which I need to change for test purposes

Answer (score 3):

Java enums are a [syntactic sugar over some boilerplate code](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/how-are-enums-implemented.html), with static atributes and some helper methods (like `values()`). Enums feature private constructors, and Groovy doesn't allow calling `new` on an enum. So it gets kinda hacky trying to workaround this.

Answer (score 2):

No. Either you have `enum` (which is always a fixed set of choices) or you have a dynamic set of choices (which isn't an `enum`).

Use a `Set` instead.